# css effect line under area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm new to front end developpement, and i have created a design in photoshop, i'm porting it to html/css, but i have a little problem :

[image]

i want to add the bottom line that is a little darker when the element is in hover

here is my code

css :

```
#global_left_nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;    
    font-family: "Lobster1";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5a4e4e;
}


#global_left_nav ul li{
    background: #2e2828 url("images/diagonal_pattern.png") repeat;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;

    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;

    position: relative;

    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0;
}

#global_left_nav ul li:hover {
    color: #c43a3a;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #000,
        0 1px 0 #000;
}
```

html :

```
<nav id="global_left_nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Acceuil</li>
            <li>Forum</li>
            <li>Event</li>
            <li>Live</li>
            <li>Equipes</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
#global_left_nav ul li:hover { border-bottom: 2px solid #000; }
```

By the way, it's "Accueil" not "Acceuil" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `border-bottom` property to your `li`:

```
#global_left_nav ul li:hover {
    color: #c43a3a;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #000, 0 1px 0 #000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}
```

This adds a 3px line in black to your ul when it's hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#global_left_nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  height: 45px;
}
```

Here is live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hv81rb5u/3/

This will give you the desired effect, and also, the buttons will not be "jumping" when you hover on them.